# How to monitor MQ within ITRS Geneos

Tags: ibm-mq, geneos, itrs

Can anyone possibly give an example of how to setup within ITRS how to monitor an MQ queue using the mq-queue plugin?  I have two screenshots below of what it is looking for.  I am not sure how this would help us to determine how many messages are stuck within the queue?

[image: MQ_1]
[image: MQ_2]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52738075/8000647 you may be able to add something here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings under the Advanced tab tell the plugin how to connect to the IBM MQ queue manager.  How you configure these settings would depend on how the SVRCONN channel is configured on the queue manager.  If you have any specific questions about these settings please update the question with more details.

On your queue manager you need to have a SVRCONN channel defined that will allow you to connect with a user that has been provided the following permissions:

- +connect +dsp on the qmgr.
- +put +inq on the SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE
- +get +dsp on the SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE
- +dsp +inq on any local queue you want to monitor

The settings on the Basic tab tell the plugin the name of the queue manager, the names of the queues on that queue manager, and the information you want to monitor (Columns).  You can only monitor local queues.  You would specify the queue names you want to monitor either one on each line using "matches" or if they all have a similar prefix you can use "startsWith" to match multiple queues.

To monitor how many messages are on the queue you can chose the "currentQueueDepth" column which will show how many messages are on the queue at the time of the sample.

If you have MONQ turned on for the queue you can also use oldestMsgAge to monitor for the length of time the oldest message has been on the queue at the time of the sample.

The documentation for the MQ-QUEUE plugin is located at the following link and contains detailed information on the configuration: https://resources.itrsgroup.com/Netprobe/middleware/mq-queue.html