# Getting reason code 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED and Channel authentication records are disabled

Tags: ibm-mq

An application needs to clear a local queue using PCF commands. The application is getting reason code 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED. Channel authentication records are disabled.What are the minimum required permissions needs to assign to the application users.
A blank MCAUSER in the server connection channel.
or Connect authority to the queue manager object and Clear authority to the queue.

Comment: Is this a test question?  Sounds very vague.

Comment: yes it is one of the sample test question.The options they asked were A blank MCAUSER in the server connection channel. or Connect authority to the queue manager object and Clear authority to the queue.

Answer (score 2):

If you view the AMQERR01.LOG it should show you what object and permission is missing, these errors are enabled by default on any supported version of MQ, in older now unsupported versions you would need to set a ENV variable to see these errors in the AMQERR01.LOG.

In general you would need the following permissions:

- +connect +dsp on the qmgr.
- +put +inq on the SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE
- +get +dsp on the SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE
- +dsp +inq +clr on any local queue you want clear

---

Reference two other answers I provided related permissions required for PCF commands:
[IBM MQ - Permissions - Read perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754974/ibm-mq-permissions-read-perspective/43765775#43765775)
[How to monitor MQ within ITRS Geneos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369704/how-to-monitor-mq-within-itrs-geneos/41422909#41422909)

Comment: You should also check connection authentication, if you are using V8+.