# ITRS, NetProbe, MQ QUEUE PLUG-IN without libmqic.so

Tags: ibm-mq, geneos, itrs

We need to configure MQ QUEUE PLUG-IN connecting a RHEL Linux server. Below is version details.

Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     8.0.0.5
Level:       p800-005-160516.2
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.x86_64

http://resources.itrsgroup.com/docs/geneos/4.4.0/Netprobe/middleware/mq-queue.html

As per ITRS support we need libmqic.so - which is part of MQ Client Package. But since the server has MQ server installed we are not keen to install MQ Client.

So question is.

1. Can MQ Server and Client co-exist in same server ?
2. Its not logical that MQ server do not have equivalent of libmqic.so package. What is the equivalent of this in server installation ?
3. Can we just copy libmqic.so from a client installation and use ?

Any input on this would be great.  Thank you.

Regards,
Dwija

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MQServer bundle from IBM includes RPMs for both client and server libraries.

You can check what is installed with this command (sort/paste/column just format it nice):

```
rpm -qa | grep MQSeries | sort | paste -s -d' \n' | column -t
```

You should see something like the following:

```
MQSeriesClient-8.0.0-4.x86_64     MQSeriesClient-U8005-8.0.0-5.x86_64
MQSeriesGSKit-8.0.0-4.x86_64      MQSeriesGSKit-U8005-8.0.0-5.x86_64
MQSeriesJava-8.0.0-4.x86_64       MQSeriesJava-U8005-8.0.0-5.x86_64
MQSeriesJRE-8.0.0-4.x86_64        MQSeriesJRE-U8005-8.0.0-5.x86_64
MQSeriesMan-8.0.0-4.x86_64        MQSeriesMan-U8005-8.0.0-5.x86_64
MQSeriesRuntime-8.0.0-4.x86_64    MQSeriesRuntime-U8005-8.0.0-5.x86_64
MQSeriesSamples-8.0.0-4.x86_64    MQSeriesSamples-U8005-8.0.0-5.x86_64
MQSeriesSDK-8.0.0-4.x86_64        MQSeriesSDK-U8005-8.0.0-5.x86_64
MQSeriesServer-8.0.0-4.x86_64     MQSeriesServer-U8005-8.0.0-5.x86_64
```

The 8.0.0-4 packages are the base install and the U8005 packages are the update to fixpack 8.0.0.5.

As long as you have the MQSeriesClient* packages installed you will have access to the libraries required by ITRS NetProbe MQ QUEUE PLUG-IN.

I do not know of any reason why a MQ Admin would have an issue with installing those packages that come as part of the MQ Server bundle.

If there is some reason they do not want to install those packages then another work around is to download the redistributable client (google MQC8 for the download link).  You can just extract the tar into any location on the server and then make sure the LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to the locate you extracted the files to either the lib (32bit) or lib64 (64bit) sub directory.  You can run `file netprobe` to check if it is 32bit or 64bit to see which is appropriate.  If you need more details on this option let me know and I can add more.